# How to disable Keyboard input when using slider in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, keyboard, widget, slider

I am listening to keyboard with RawKeyboardListener to use the arrows keys for some function.
The problem is that I also have a Slider widget that is effected by the arrows keys pressing.
Does anyone knows how to disable the keyboard listener in the Slider widget?

```
class _MovSensitivtySlider extends StatelessWidget {
  const _MovSensitivtySlider({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: Utils.getWinWidth(context) * 0.2,
      height: Utils.getWinHeight(context) * 0.1,
      child: Slider(
        value: context.watch<GimbalControlBloc>().state.movSensitivity,
        activeColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 255, 8),
        max: 10,
        min: 1,
        divisions: 10,
        label: "Gimbal Movement Sensitivity",
        onChanged: (double value) {
          context
              .read<GimbalControlBloc>()
              .add(GimbalMovSensitivityEvent(movSensitivity: value));
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```